# Laravel summernote HTML output

Tags: laravel-5, summernote

I'm using Laravel 5 and Summernote editor, with some issues.
I have a page where I can write an article and then save it which works fine.
But when i try to edit the article, I get the html code in the textarea instead of getting the formatted content.

in `add-article.blade.php`:

```
{!! Form::textarea('body','',['name'=>'body','id'=>'body','class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

in `edit-article.blade.php`:

```
{!! Form::textarea('body',$article->body,['name'=>'body','id'=>'body','class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue.

Fixed it by doing this on javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var options = {
    height: 200
  };

  var text = $('#text');
  text.summernote(options);
  text.summernote('code',text.text()); //here is the trick
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Not only that please use

```
{!! $article->body !!}
```

Comment: worked laravel 5.7. this should simply answer . thank you

Answer (score 1):

You also need to take care of images if you are going to store the summernote content in a database.

As summernote encodes images into `base64` format which adds tens of thousands of characters to your content which is not feasible for storing in the database.

See [this tutorial](https://www.kerneldev.com/2018/01/11/using-summernote-wysiwyg-editor-with-laravel/) for more info.